# PHP array - create an array from an array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, multidimensional-array

Hello I have POST array that looks like this,

```
Array (
  [email_address] => Array ( 
    [0] => simon@simonainley.info  
    [1] => simon2@simonainley.info 
  ) 
  [firstname] => Array ( 
    [0] => Simon 
    [1] => Simon2 
  ) 
  [surname] => Array ( 
    [0] => Ainley 
    [1] => Ainley2 
  ) 
  [companies_company_id] => NULL,
  [save_user] => Save User 
)
```

I wanting to create an new array where I would get the first email_address, firstname, and surname into an array, deal with that data and then proceed to the next email-address, firstname and surname.

Is this possible? I have tried this code,

```
$newArray = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)  {
    $newArray[] = $value;
}
```

however that code just produces this,

```
Array (
  [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => simon@simonainley.info 
      [1] => simon2@simonainley.info
  )
  [1] => Array ( 
      [0] => Simon 
      [1] => Simon2
  ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Ainley [1] => Ainley2 ) [3] => [4] => Save User ) 1
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Something with the array data you've in your question does look wrong. I edited a bit in case it's NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = count($_POST['firstname']);
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i ++) {
  $result[] = array(
    'email_address' => $_POST['email_address'][0],
    'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'][0],
    'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'][0]
  );
}
```

or (if the numeric indices have any meaning)

```
$result = array();
foreach (array_keys($_POST['email_address']) as $index) {
  $result[$index] = array(
    'email_address' => $_POST['email_address'][$index],
    'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'][$index],
    'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'][$index]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    $count=0;
    foreach($value as $val)
    {
        $newArray[$count++]=Array($key=>$val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to re-order the elements into the `$_POST` array:

```
$users = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $values) {
    if (is_array($values)) {
        foreach($values as $index => $value) {
            $users[$index][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

With the data you provided, it will give you this in the `$users` array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [email_address] => simon@simonainley.info
        [firstname] => Simon
        [surname] => Ainley
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [email_address] => simon2@simonainley.info
        [firstname] => Simon2
        [surname] => Ainley2
    )
```

Elements in `$_POST` that are not an array are ignored and filtered out.